# Adding .sty files into tex

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu

I am new to TeX and I want to add a .sty file. But when I tried all the ways described on this site. I could not do it, as it requires the permission of the folder to add the .sty file.I am a Linux user.

Update 1:
I have tried:
copying the .sty file in 
`/usr/local/share/texmf` but I did not find any file here. Again I have tried copying here: `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex` but did not get any permission.

Again I have tried with the `/home/username` and I was shocked that I did not saw any folder `texmf` .

After these I have also tried the ways as advised in the comment section as well as the answer. But did not work.

Any further help will be appreciated.

Comment: If the *.sty file is in a path known to TeXLive, than `\usepackage{*}` would do. If that is not the case, copy the *.sty file into the directory your *.tex file is located and then use `\usepackage{*}`.

Comment: Sorry it is not working

Comment: If you do not have the permissions to write on the TeX file's folder you are lost. If you have them copy the sty file to that folder. If you want to install it for all documents look at the other posts about texmf-local and if you want to install it for all users and documents you are equally lost without permissions.

Comment: Please give me a detailed answer. I have tried the way as explained by @Skillmon but did not work. I would appreciate if anyone give me a detailed answer.

Comment: I guess that some people are confused because it is not clear how to interpret your question. Do you want to (i) include a standard style file to your document or (ii) add a .sty file to the system such that it can be used in your TeX documents? Your statement on the permissions suggests that it is the second possibility, but the fact that you tried @Skillmon's suggestion hints at the first. It would be great if you could rewrite your question such that it is clear what you mean, and specify what you tried.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't have the permissions to add the .sty file to your home TeX directory. If you can't do that, you can always put it in any other folder you have access to.

For example, if your .sty file is named file.sty, you can copy it to the same folder as the .tex file and write in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{file}
```

In general, if you don't want to or can't copy the .sty file to the .tex folder, you can write the relative path to where it is saved, like this:

```
\usepackage{../folder1/folder2/file}
```

The problem with this approach is that you will have to either copy the .sty file every time you use it or write the relative path to it.

Comment: The problem with the option "can't copy the .sty file to the .tex folder" is, that in general means he doesn't have write permission on that folder, in which case he can't use LaTeX in the first place, because he doesn't have permission to write the output nor .aux files.

Comment: What is the solution to it?

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty to not having write permission? Ask your sys-admin to grant them. If that's not an option but you have read permissions on the directory copy the files to a directory you have write privileges to and work in that folder.

Comment: How to do it? Elaborate it.

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty If the problem is write permission, there is NO "how to do it." It cannot be done, unless you are the system adminstrator. If you are, then changing permission is a system command, not a TeX command. If you are not, one possibility is to locate whoever is the system administrator, and ask for the change. You may or may not get it. BETTER: Does the computer have a USB port? Obtain your own USB stick, and put your files there, because you will have the necessary permission.

Answer (score 1):

Add the .sty file in the folder where you have your .tex file (the source code). Then, in the preamble add

> \usepackage{file}

For example, I wanted to add multicols.sty file. After having googled for multicols.sty and downloaded it, I pasted it in the folder containing my tex code. Then, in the preamble, I added

> \usepackage{multicols}

Note: 'multicols' in 'usepackage' is written without the extension '.sty'.

Comment: It would probably be a better idea to install the package properly using a package manager.